# How to get JSON HTTP request body from error report with elmah?

Tags: c#, .net, elmah

I'm using Elmah to log exceptions. Elmah is great at logging request bodies if the request is a Form-based request (i.e. Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded), but with JSON based requests where the content type is application/json, the request body is nowhere to be found in the error reports. Anyone know where I can find this request body so that I can properly diagnose my exceptions?

As a clarification on what I mean by JSON based requests, here's an example raw HTTP request with JSON as the request body:

```
PUT http://mycompany.com/api/v1.0/me HTTP/1.1
Host: mycompany.com
Content-Length: 20
Content-Type: application/json

{"city":"Vancouver"}
```